# Cordova Android App Google Plus Authentication Error 10

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, certificate, google-plus

I want to use google plus authentication in my cordova app.

**1. Generate keystore**

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore <keystoreName>.keystore -alias <Keystore AliasName> -keyalg <Key algorithm> -keysize <Key size> -validity <Key Validity in Days>
```

**2. Create android release version**

```
cordova build android --release
```

**3. Sign My Apk**

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <keystoreName>.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk <alias>
```

**4. Optimize my APK**

```
zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk <output name>.apk
```

**5. ADD android app in: http://console.firebase.google.com.**

**6. Get hash from my keystore**

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore <keystoreName>.keystore -list -v -alias <alias>
```

**7. Add SHA1 hash for my adroid app**

**8. After that i can see client id for android in: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=**

**9. I'm install this plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus.**

**10. My code in app:**

```
window.plugins.googleplus.getSigningCertificateFingerprint(
    function (fingerprint) {
        alert(fingerprint); // SHA1 HASH - It's same like in console.firebase.google.com
    }
);

window.plugins.googleplus.login(
    {
        'scopes': '',
        'webClientId': '62......39.6-..................jjka5b...v87q7.apps.googleusercontent.com', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
        'offline': true,
    },
    function (obj) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
    },
    function (msg) {
        alert('error: ' + msg); // error 10
    }
);
```

**I'm install apk on my android device and always get error 10.**

I installed and successfully use facebook plugin for cordova. It's work good! But i can't solve problem with google. What am I doing wrong?

Can anybody help me...

I regenerated keystore... Reinstall cordova... Reinstall googlepus plugin...

Comment: I have faced the same problem, uninstall all the plugins using Cordova CLI and install them again.

Comment: I reinstalled... And try another versions 5.1.1, 5.1.2... No effect...

Comment: May be problem with settings in Google console... Can anybody help me...

Comment: You have provided the REVERSED_CLIENT_ID, at the time of plugin installation?

Comment: Yes, i add it. It's need only for IOS. I try to create empty project in another version of cordova, added google-plus-plugin... And i'm get error 10 again... May be something wrong with my setting in google console... I don't know...

Comment: I have been created debug version: cordova build android. Get hash from debug keystore: keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore. Add hash in console.firebase.google.com for my android app. Google create for me client id in console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials. I use new client id in debug app version. And i get error 10. I can't understand what i am doing wrong... Another version of cordova... Different plugins... May be problem with my account... Can anybody show me the way to drive...

Comment: I have published version in play market... And may be it's signed another key... But i don't use google plus auth in it...

Comment: would suggest you to follow each step again mentioned for installation of https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#3-google-api-setup

Answer (score 3):

**My problem solved!!!**

I use clientID **"Web client (auto created by Google Service)"** instead of clientID **"Android client for com.android.app (auto created by Google Service)"**. It's work! I get token and user data!

Comment: Hi, can I know the steps how you solved this issue? I'm facing the same

Comment: used ClientID where? pass as a variable (REVERSE_CLIENTID or WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENTID) while installing the googleplus plugin or pass this to webClientID in the googleplus.login({}) function, have tried all the combinations still the issue remains error 10

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error because I was trying to log-in from within the Emulator. This fails because the the emulator installs the `app-debug.apk` which does not have proper SHA1 fingerprints, unlike the signed `apk` or `aab` ( bundle ).

I installed the signed version I generated from Android Studio and installed that to a actual device which made it work.